# How to use AttributeConverter(JPA 2.1) in JPA XML mapping file?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class that contains a `XMLGregorianCalendar` property, which is not a basic type supported by hibernate. The User Guide tells me an `AttributeConverter` is a solution. However I found it has to be implemented with annotation `@Converter` and I got this:

[image]

The property I need to handle is:

[image]

So I try to use hibernate mapping file, but I find no converter tags in it. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not post source code as screenshot, paste it here. Otherwise it is hard to read and not searchable.

Answer (score 3):

you can add it to your entity mapping as described in this tutorial (http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-use-jpa-type-converter-to/)

```
<entity-mappings version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">

    <entity class="x.y.Entity">
        <convert converter="x.y.CryptoConverter" attribute-name="yourField"/>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is very useful!

Comment: Sorry, can I ask one more question? the entity-mapping file is different from hibernate-mapping. Can it also be used in Hibernate?As I know, Hibernate use <class> and <property>

Comment: @YoungHarry looks like you mean persistence.xml. there is example of orm.xml with hibernate mapping as you mentioned in your question. do you really need declaring it in entity-mapping file? you can do it in annotations way too.

Comment: That is the trouble. The class I need has many JAXB annotation, and it will be use to call SOAP webservice,when i add @Entity to the  top-level class, eclipse will give a deprecation to it.

Comment: If I built a mirror class of this class, it will cost me so much time as the class has too many propeties, for example, a class has at least more than 20 properties and i have at least more than ten classes just like this

Comment: looks like it's an issue of eclipse. i have a lot of same classes in one of my projects, all works well. all JPA annotations mixed with JAXB annotations without any troubles. @Convert annotations are used there too.

Comment: Thx! I will try. Is there any suggestions about how to find why the eclipse give me a deprecation?

Comment: hmm... guess you are using Entity annotation from Hibernate libraries. what about using JPA javax.persistence.Entity annotation instead?

Comment: Thanks for you advice! Does Hibernate could use JPA's annotations?

Comment: Hibernate is JPA provider since version 3.6 as i remember.

Comment: Well , I use Entity from javax.persistance ,the eclipse do not give deprecation but the Entity from Hibernate will be. After I google , I found that@Entity is deprecated after 4.1.is it true?@ivanenok

Comment: yep. only JPA annotations should be used in your entity declaration. in some rare cases hibernate specific annotations are usable.